# Given n number of matches where it takes k cards to come up with a match, what is the expected value for number of turns to match all cards?

Tags: probability

To make it clearer what I'm saying, I have the card matching game, or concentration, in mind when thinking of this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game). I have seen this solved for when one is trying to match two cards, but not 3 or more.

The specific rules used for this game are that a turn consists of lifting up one card, then the other, then the other and so on. Each time a new set of k cards is lifted up, that counts as a turn.